# Prove $\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}+\frac{f'(\eta)}{g'(\eta)}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, rolles-theorem

Let $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$, differentiable in $(a,b)$, such that  $f(0)=g(0)=f(1)=0$, $g'(x)\neq0$.

Prove:

$\exists\xi,\eta\in(0,1),\xi<\eta,$

$$\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}+\frac{f'(\eta)}{g'(\eta)}=0$$

I have no idea about it, but I can post some link which I think is useful.

[question1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927339/existence-of-xi-and-eta-such-that-f-xif-eta-xi-eta)

[question2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018255/prove-exists-xi-eta-in-0-1-such-that-f-xif-eta-xi-eta?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[question3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912006/a-problem-about-the-differential-mean-value-theorem-2%ce%b7f1c2-1f%ce%b7-f%ce%be/2912029#2912029)

This is a question of a real-analysis book which named 'Mathematical analysis course'(Author:Shi Jihuai,Chang Gengzhe).

Book Name:数学分析教程(Mathematical analysis course)

Author: 史济怀 常庚哲

My attempt

When there are two parameters in question,we can express them by a node which 
associated with both.

And then we can remove the node by some operations.For this question, We can see the answer of I posted.

**I want to get a proof,and a way to solve two-parameter($\xi,\eta$) question**

Comment: do you have a source for this problem? In case of having no idea about the solution, while the mention of similar questions was nice you can also mention  the source. Also, see if any of the questions whose links you gave, are special cases of the question above, and see what you can modify in that answer to get the answer in the general case.

Comment: This is a question of a real-analysis book.I think the three questions that I posted are similar.They all have two-parameter.And I'm trying to solve the question I ask.

Comment: @梦里年华似烟花 If you don't mind can you please mention the name of book. Thanks.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician It's a Chinese book,named 《数学分析教程》(常庚哲，史济怀著).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), since $g(0)=0$, $\exists t\in (0,1)$ such that $g(t)=g(1)/2$.

By the [Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy's_mean_value_theorem), $\exists \xi \in(0,t)$ such that
$$\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}=\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{g(t)-g(0)}=\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}.$$
Again, by the same reason as before, $\exists \eta \in(t,1)$ such that
$$-\frac{f(t)}{g(1)-g(t)}=\frac{f(1)-f(t)}{g(1)-g(t)}=\frac{f'(\eta)}{g'(\eta)}.$$
Then $0<\xi<\eta<1$ and
$$\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}+\frac{f'(\eta)}{g'(\eta)}=
\frac{f(t)(g(1)-2g(t))}{g(t)(g(1)-g(t))}=0.$$

Comment: For the two-parameter question, I find it is solved by a node which associated with both usually.For example, $\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}+\frac{f'(\eta)}{g'(\eta)}$,and then $\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$ is removed.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and write down your attempt?

Comment: I think your answer has introduced the way.@Robert Z

Comment: In order to avoid downvotes, it is better that you say something about the background (english title of the book, authors?) and your attempt.

Comment: Ok,Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: [AMM](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/amm.html)The answer of site is yours？

Comment: @梦里年华似烟花 Yes, they are mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89881/discussion-between--and-robert-z).